# Front Page Display (Your latest posts) Blank, other pages fine

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new to PHP and WordPress and I want to develop my theme from scratch.

From the reading settings on WordPress Dashboard I have set for the Front page displays option to 'Your latest posts', but the homepage is blank with no header or footer, although every other page works just fine.

Here is my code for index.php:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php 
    if(have_posts()): 

    while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>

    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

    <small>Posted on: <?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> at <?php the_time('g:i a'); ?>, in <?php the_category(); ?></small>

    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>

    <hr>

    <?php endwhile; 

    endif;

    ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Thank you.

Comment: Any error in the browser console or php logs?

Comment: How can I fix this please? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be loading another template which is a blank fil. WordPress has a hierarchy of templates set out in https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#front-page-display.
For your situation the hierarchy is front-page.php, home.php, index.php, so check those first two.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I do not have the front-page.php and home.php at this level of my development, must I create it before the homepage displays because every other pages works fine except the homepage.

Comment: Thanks. home.php was actually in the theme folder and was empty. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

Can you test to register again the permalinks ? You go i nthe dashboard on settings menu > permalinks and you click save.

Sometimes Wordpress need to register again permalinks te reset htaccess when you developp some action ( like create custom post type or others )

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried but its not working, still the same blank homepage but every other page works fine.

Comment: Did you enabled ('WP_DEBUG' to true in wp-config to see if there is any error displaying ? if no, go to your www directory, and open wp-config.php and find define('WP_DEBUG', false); and change with this define('WP_DEBUG', true); and go check your homepage

Comment: And if you remplace all content of index.php by just a "test" there is something ? Did you have url to see ?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. James Jones' answer below has solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: ah yes i diden't understood why nothing work because you said you haven't home.php files :)